# Flask and SQLAlchemy db.session.commit() is not working properly on updates

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Just trying to update a username but it isn't updating in the database even though current_user.username has updated. I'm using mySQL, SQLAlchemy and flask.

```
@app.route('/account', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def account():

form = UpdateAccountForm()

if form.validate_on_submit():
    current_user.username = form.username.data
    db.session.commit()
    flash(f"Updated Account information, welcome {form.username.data}, {current_user.username},",  'success')
    return redirect(url_for('account'))
elif request.method == 'GET':
    form.username.data = current_user.username


return render_template('account.html', title='Account', form=form)

class UpdateAccountForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=4, max=20)])
    submit = SubmitField('Update')

def validate_username(self, username):
    if username.data != current_user.username:
        user = db.session.query(models.User).filter_by(username=username.data).first()
        if user:
            raise ValidationError('That username is taken. Please choose another.')
        return user
```

Comment: Fix the code formatting please.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? 
Are you sure the form.username.data is actually capturing the data from the form?

Also i do not see a
`db.session.add(current_user)` 
statement, you have a commit statement but where do you add the data to be commiterd

Comment: No errors, yes it does capture the data because i can post the new username on the webpage. current_user is a function from flask login, it detects what user is logged in. So that user already exists in the db. current_user.username = form.username.data should swap to the updated username and commit() should enter that in the db but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same problem and I searched a lot then I got this syntax, then I realize that i forgot this to add on account.html

```
<form action="{{ url_for('contact') }}" method=post>
{{ form.hidden_tag() }}
```